# Attempting to add list members to MailChimp list using a plugin within Nuxt3, getting an error stating addListMemberWithHttpInfo is not a function

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, mailchimp-api-v3.0, nuxt3

I'm trying to use the MailChimp Marketing API to add members to one of my MailChimp list's, however, after creating the following plugin within my Vue3/Nuxt3 project:

```
import MailchimpMarketing from '@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing'

MailchimpMarketing.setConfig({
    apiKey: '**************',
    server: '****',
})

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.provide('mailchimp', {
        $addListMember: MailchimpMarketing.lists.addListMember,
    })
})
```

And then attempting to implement it within the following function:

```
<script setup>
const { $mailchimp } = useNuxtApp()
const handleSubmit = (event) => {


    const listId = '*******'
    const myForm = event.target
    const formData = new FormData(myForm)

    const run = async () => {
        const response = await $mailchimp.$addListMember(listId, {
            email_address: formData.get('email'),
            status: 'pending',
        })
        console.log(response)
    }

    run();
}
</script>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ListsApi.js:3947 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.addListMemberWithHttpInfo is not a function
    at Object.addListMember [as $addListMember] (ListsApi.js:3947:17)
    at run (GlobalFooter.vue:339:1)
    at handleSubmit (GlobalFooter.vue:346:1)
    at chunk-OE4IQ2AX.js?v=69d090bb:9148:1
    at callWithErrorHandling (chunk-OE4IQ2AX.js?v=69d090bb:1557:1)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (chunk-OE4IQ2AX.js?v=69d090bb:1565:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (chunk-OE4IQ2AX.js?v=69d090bb:8175:1)
```

Curious if anyone has any tips on how to resolve this?

I'm expecting to see a 200 response from the MailChimp Marketing API to let me know that the email address was successfully added to the member list.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

`addListMember` expects to access `this.addListMemberWithHttpInfo` that means =>  `useNuxtApp().$mailchimp` *(the provided object)* must has `addListMemberWithHttpInfo` which is not the case.

### Solution:

**1- You can either provide** the whole object `MailchimpMarketing` from the plugin

```
nuxtApp.provide('mailchimp', MailchimpMarketing)
```

then you call it as:

```
$mailchimp.lists.addListMember(...)
```

**2- Or, alternatively, you can provide** a function that calls `MailchimpMarketing.lists.addListMember` rather than providing it directly:

```
nuxtApp.provide('mailchimp', {
    $addListMember: (/*someparams*/) => {
      MailchimpMarketing.lists.addListMember(/*someparams*/)
    }
})
```